# Ports are open but not possible to connect with it

Tags: php, sockets

I have used socket to check the status for proxy with ports (IP:Port) to see if the proxy is working or not, i have used socket to do that( not curl or fsockopen

I'm using [this codes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php) the second example with a little changes.

I will try to explain the current problem which i have with a live example.

IP: 109.195.98.21 have 2 open ports (80,3129)

Socket can open the both ports however 3129 is the real one which can connect and use it as a proxy and not possible for port 80 even it's open, i really can't understand the reason and how i just can detect the open port which is open and possible to connect with it like (3129) . any idea please? thanks.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What exactly are you trying to do and what fails? Please show relevant code.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok i have edited my Q, this site is doing the same job [here](http://incloak.com/ports/), Also you can clickhere to see the [scan result here](http://s8.postimg.org/pp72cbas5/98844.png)

Comment: Use netstat to see weather the port actually IS open and check yo firewall. Put more information into the question, source and destination IP and Port,.. direction of data..

Comment: @user I meant your last sentence: _"Socket can open the both ports however 3129 is the real one which can connect and use it as a proxy and not possible for port 80 even it's open, i really can't understand the reason and how i just can detect the open port which is open and possible to connect with it like (3129)"_. I really can't figure out what you mean with this.

Comment: Website -> nmap shell execute -> results back to browser, you don't need socket programing there? Be aware portscans are not legal to use in some situations

Comment: @DanFromGermany so i only can use socket to check if the port is open or not, but i can't check the possibility to connect to it or not by using php?

Comment: @CodeCaster after i scanned the ip it have 2 open ports, right? now try to check which one can be used for the browser as IP:Port prxoy, the answer is 109.195.98.21:3129 and not the same for port 80 even if it open. the will get the same [result here](http://incloak.com/proxy-checker/)

Answer (score 1):

So this simplified code will let you check if a port is open or not and that's it.

```
<?php
  $socket = socket_create( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP );
  $response = socket_connect( $socket, '109.195.98.21', 3129 );

  if ( $response === false ) {
    printf( 'socket_connect failed: %s',
      socket_strerror( socket_last_error( $socket ) ) );
  } else {
    printf( 'Connected!' );
    socket_close( $socket );
  }
?>
```

However, since you're after an actual proxy, and as you say, there is no difference between merely opening 80 vs. 3129 on your server you'll have to send some data downstream and see what happens.

This depends on what proxy is running. SOCKS? HTTP?

For HTTP, you need to send an HTTP request and expect a sane response. Some HTTP proxies redirect to unwanted locations regardless of what you request. So you'd send a tiny HTTP payload and see what it gets you.

For SOCKS, read the protocols http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS#Protocol and send the required payloads to verify whether they work or not.

Use [`socket_write`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-write.php), [`socket_read`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php) for this.

More information:

- http://www.oooff.com/php-affiliate-seo-blog/php-automation-coding/easy-php-proxy-checker-writing-tutorial/
- [Help to test if a proxy works using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977923/help-to-test-if-a-proxy-works-using-php) using `fsockopen` instead, which supports talking to proxies out of the box and easier than trying to emulate the protocol

Of course, an easier way would be to use `netcat` or `curl` perhaps.